# Download the last created o modified file from a list of files from a ftp server in python

Tags: python, datetime, ftp

I have the next code, which downloads zip files, but I need just the last modified or created file from the ftp, not all of them.
For example, I have:

- one_20140220.xml.zip
- one_20140221.xml.zip
- one_20140222.xml.zip

In this case I need to download just the "one_20140222.xml.zip" file.
Can someone help me please?. I'm new using python. How do I proceed next?

```
#CODE
import ftplib
import os
import fnmatch
import datetime
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta


ftp_server='ftp.blabla.com'
ftp_user='user'
ftp_pass='pass'


def download():
    print 'dowloading from ftp server'

os.chdir('/root/dir/zip')
s = ftplib.FTP(ftp_server, ftp_user, ftp_pass)

s.cwd('one/two/')
fileList = s.nlst()
targetList = [fileName for fileName in fileList if fnmatch.fnmatch(fileName,'*.zip')]
if (targetList == []):
    print 'No files to process'
for file in targetList:
    print 'downloaded file: ' + file
    try:
        fileOut=open(file,'wb')
        s.retrbinary('RETR '+file,fileOut.write)
        fileOut.close()
    except:
        print 'Cant open file'

s.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

given that

```
filename1 = 'one_20140220.xml.zip'
filename2 = 'one_20140221.xml.zip'
file1 = filename1.split('.')[0].split('_')
file2 = filename2.split('.')[0].split('_')
print file1[1] < file2[1]
print file1[1], file2[1]

>>> True
>>> 20140220 20140221
```

This should let you do the comparison checking. Note that in this case you do not have to convert the value of the date from a string since the string comparison (of year month day) gives the correct result.

You can set up a dictionary with the key being filex[0] and the value being a list of all the filex[1] values. Then just loop over the dictionary and pick out the max value.

```
 mydict ={filex[0]: [val1, val2, val3 ...], ... }

 for f in mydict:
   filename = f + max(mydict[f]) + '.xml.zip'
   # Process the file name within a function
   dofile(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but maybe I explained myself wrong. I need to get the last created o modified zip file automatically, not make a comparison. I tried this and it does't work for me.

Comment: I appreciate your help though

Comment: @gegQ I meant that once you get the correct file name (by using a max on the date list) you can then open it automatically. I showed the comparison in order to show that the comparison or the max works. In this case you would get filename as the appropriate name and dofile() would open it and do the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your files are named like in your example, this is pretty simple

```
import datetime
filenameFmt = "one_%Y%M%d.xml.zip" # You will need to update this to match the filenames
def getEarliestFile(arrayOfFiles):
    namesWithDate = []
    for filename in arrayOfFiles:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(filename,filenameFmt)
        namesWithDate.append((filename,dt))

    #sort the array in ascending order
    namesWithDate = sorted(namesWithDate,key = lambda x: x[1])
    #Grab and return the newest one
    filename, dt = namesWithDate[-1]
    return filename
```

You can pass this function a complete list of all the filenames, it returns the filename of the newest one.